# I'm an undergrad building a railgun and I need assistance!

Tags: mosfet, supercapacitor

I am a physics undergrad that chose his senior project to build a low voltage railgun, however I am running into a few different issues.

1.) The paper mentions a "flyback diode bank" which I have never heard of. I assume it is several flyback diodes connected together to prevent high voltage spikes, however it is only briefly mentioned in the paper and it is not clearly shown.

2.) There is also a MOSFET driver circuit which is mentioned but was not mentioned in great detail. Would I be able to create my own triggering system for the railgun, or could I possibly use disposable camera circuits instead?

For reference I am using three 3400 Farad capacitors in parallel, and have almost all of the electrical components mentioned in the paper. I currently do not have any parts machined and am in the process of doing so. I plan on decreasing the length of the rails due to the smaller current used.

https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.4760659
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110005535.pdf

The first link is the paper I am basing my project on, however the second link is very similiar and is free.

Thank you for reading and any help provided!

Comment: You should clarify what current it is you intend to use.  "Smaller" for a railgun could still be thousands of amps, and generally speaking, for the same thrust, the lower the voltage you use the higher the current needed, although this design appears to use multiple rails, mechanically in parallel and electrically in series to minimise necessary current.  I would suspect the reason a bank of flyback diodes and mosfets is used is because although the current may be low for a railgun, it is still quite large for a switch.

Comment: Have you time to change your project? A 'low anything' railgun will always have disappointing results, though you can demonstrate the principle with a wired 'slapper' circuit. A coilgun is far easier to get something going with energy levels far below 1kJ. You would use a 'bank' of anything where the required specs cannot be (economically or practically) met by a single device. Beware of sharing issues when building a bank, 2 100A diodes in parallel will probably not carry 200A.